# Stop Oracle sql query execution automatically using profile limits

Tags: sql, oracle, timeout, limit, settimeout

I want to limit Oracle user by executing query more then 15 second, for this I've created new profile with this script bellow and assign it to user.

CREATE PROFILE   jibo_test_profile   LIMIT
  
 SESSIONS_PER_USER                       UNLIMITED 
   
CPU_PER_SESSION                            UNLIMITED 
   
CPU_PER_CALL                                   1500 
   
CONNECT_TIME                                   45 
   
LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION    DEFAULT 
   
LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL           1000 
   
PRIVATE_SGA                                       15K
   
COMPOSITE_LIMIT                               5000000;

then I tried to execute simple select query (select * from something) which works more then 15 second, but it does not stops when query execution time reaches 15 second ( even 5 minute :) ),
then i tried to assign "CPU_PER_SESSION" 1500, but without any change.

Do you have any ideas why this limits does not works for me?

Comment: Please run this query `select username, profile
from dba_users where username = 'USERNAME';` to check if the profile has been assigned to the user. If no, then run `ALTER username PROFILE  jibo_test_profile` command.

Comment: I've checked it and profile is assigned to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of problem was, that resource limit was set on "false", so profile limits were not working for user.

To use profile limits, RESOURCE_LIMIT should be set on "true"

ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_LIMIT = true;